# Rails 5 ActionCable on Heroku uninitialized constant NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket

I'm aware of the fact that Heroku only allows 2 ports, i.e. 80 and 443 for connection, which is why you need to run a separate server for WebSockets. I came across [this guide](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-action-cable-to-heroku/) which claims to allow you to run both processes on the same server. I also changed the line:
`if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)` to:
`::WebSocket::Driver.websocket?(env)` as per a comment by a user, since I'm not using Faye.
However, I get the error **uninitialized constant ChatActionCable (NameError)**. I tried the guide on [this page](https://hackhands.com/rails-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-class-solution/), yet no gain.

My application.rb file looks like this:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

module Third
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

TIA.

**Update**: The problem with the guide was the name of the middleware file. I changed it to `chat_action_cable.rb` and at least the middleware starts to run. Now the problem lies with `::WebSocket::Driver.websocket?(env)` line as Uninitialized constant, NameError.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the examples online are incomplete.

Your middleware should inherit from `ActionCable::Connection::WebSocket`

```
class ChatActionCable < ActionCable::Connection::WebSocket
  def initialize(app, options={})
    @app = app
 end

  def call(env)
    if ::WebSocket::Driver.websocket?(env)
      ActionCable.server.call(env)
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

#### For people looking how to setup ActionCable with Heroku, here is a step by step guide :

Create the middleware file :

```
/app/middleware/chat_action_cable.rb

class ChatActionCable < ActionCable::Connection::WebSocket
  def initialize(app, options={})
    @app = app
 end

  def call(env)
    if ::WebSocket::Driver.websocket?(env)
      ActionCable.server.call(env)
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Set it up in config :

```
/config/environments/production.rb

config.middleware.use ChatActionCable  
config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://your-heroku-app.herokuapp.com/"
```

Set redis plugin on heroku (it should already be included) :

```
 heroku plugins:install heroku-redis (in case)
```

Create a new redis heroku instance :

```
 heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a young-home-19338
 (replace young-home-19338 with your instance name)
```

It will set a `REDIS_URL` env, you can grab it with :

```
heroku config | grep REDIS
```

Now, set the config for actionCable :

```
/config/cable.yml
development: &development  
  :url: redis://localhost:6379
  :host: localhost
  :port: 6379
  :timeout: 1
  :inline: true
test: *development  
production: &production  
  :url:     redis://redistogo:192csd9c30ca49585ce9d85daf0fer90@tarpon.redistogo.com:49382
  :host: tarpon.redistogo.com
  :port: 49382
  :password: 349f93483fv9erfv849dfvdfbds9
  :inline: true
  :timeout: 1
```

The host is between `@` and `:`
The port is after `:`
The password :

```
heroku run rails c
uri = URI.parse(<your redis URL>)
uri.password
```

That should be all.

I used these two articles as reference :

http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-action-cable-to-heroku/

https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable